# Why does my adt emulator does not show the activity using menu?

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator

I don't see any errors in my code, and I did what the tutorial taught me. I'm quite new to android and new member here(please be gentle).

Sorry guys for not clearing up my question.
The thing is when i click the menu button on the right side of the emulator the menu shows.. **yes it shows the inflate  but every time i choose one of those menu nothing happens** , it doesnt do anything at all.

Anyway here's the code for the java :

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 //inflates the menu
 MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();
awesome.inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 

return true;
 }

  public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.menuSweet:
    startActivity(new Intent("Sweet"));
    return true;

case R.id.menuToast:
    Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
    "This is a toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    andEggs.show();
    return true;

}
return false;

   }`
```

Heres the xml in res/menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >




 <item 
 android:id="@+id/menuSweet"
 android:alphabeticShortcut="s"
 android:title="Open Sweet Activity" 
 android:onClick="@layout/about" />

 <item 
 android:id="@+id/menuToast"
 android:alphabeticShortcut="t"
 android:title="Open Toast Activity" />


 </menu>
```

Heres the manifest :

```
    <activity   
        android:name=".Sweet"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Sweet" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Comment: and what is your question

Comment: is this in an activity or fragment?

Comment: ive fix this yesterday! thanks for the help guys!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the default case in your switch tatement i.e.

```
default:  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

And I don't think there is any need of `return false;` ..   Remove it also .

Answer (score 0):

The second method should be called:

```
onOptionsItemSelected
```

instead of:

```
onOptionItemSelected
```

There is a missing "s" in method's name.